# Using Ext.Msg.Alert in Asp.net

Tags: extjs

```
Ext.onReady(function(){  
    if (Ext.get('ctl00_ContentBody_txtCM').dom.value == "") 
   { 
      Ext.MessageBox.alert("Status", "You have input CM!", function()
       {  
             Ext.get('ctl00_ContentBody_txtCM').focus();                 

        }     
        );             
   }
```

when submit button,it postback server before.Please help me.I using asp.net

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has anything to do with your submit button. If I'm reading this right, you fire this function:

```
function(){  
if (Ext.get('ctl00_ContentBody_txtCM').dom.value == "") 
{ 
  Ext.MessageBox.alert("Status", "You have input CM!", function()
   {  
         Ext.get('ctl00_ContentBody_txtCM').focus();                 

    }     
    );
```

Exactly once, when the Ext library is done loading. I think you should double-check your Javascript and the Ext API. For starters, remove the if() statement and try to get the message box to fire without it.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to use ext js with asp.net check out this library:

http://www.ext.net/

It helped me a lot.  After using this framework with asp.net I was able to get a better understanding of extjs and I can now clearly see how to use extjs directly if I wanted to.